# MAX / MIN function in Objective C that avoid casting issues

Tags: ios, objective-c

I had code in my app that looks like the following.  I got some feedback around a bug, when to my horror, I put a debugger on it and found that the MAX between -5 and 0 is -5!

```
NSString *test = @"short";
int calFailed = MAX(test.length - 10, 0);                      // returns -5
```

After looking at the MAX macro, I see that it requires both parameters to be of the same type.  In my case, "test.length" is an unsigned int and 0 is a signed int.  So a simple cast (for either parameter) fixes the problem.

```
NSString *test = @"short";
int calExpected = MAX((int)test.length - 10, 0);                    // returns 0
```

This seems like a nasty and unexpected side effect of this macro.  Is there another built-in method to iOS for performing MIN/MAX where the compiler would have warned about mismatching types?  Seems like this *SHOULD* have been a compile time issue and not something that required a debugger to figure out.  I can always write my own, but wanted to see if anybody else had similar issues.

Comment: You mean like `fmax`?

Answer (score 30):

Enabling `-Wsign-compare`, as suggested by FDinoff's answer is a good idea, but I thought it might be worth explaining the reason behind this in some more detail, as it's a quite common pitfall.

The problem isn't really with the `MAX` macro in particular, but with a) subtracting from an unsigned integer in a way that leads to an overflow, and b) (as the warning suggests) with how the compiler handles the comparison of signed and unsigned values in general.

The first issue is pretty easy to explain: When you subtract from an unsigned integer and the result would be negative, the result "overflows" to a very large positive value, because an unsigned integer cannot represent negative values. So `[@"short" length] - 10` will evaluate to `4294967291`.

What might be more surprising is that even without the subtraction, something like `MAX([@"short" length], -10)` will not yield the correct result (it would evaluate to `-10`, even though `[@"short" length]` would be `5`, which is obviously larger). This has nothing to do with the macro, something like `if ([@"short" length] > -10) { ... }` would lead to the same problem (the code in the if-block would *not* execute).

So the general question is: What happens exactly when you compare an unsigned integer with a signed one (and why is there a warning for that in the first place)? The compiler will convert both values to a common type, according to certain rules that can lead to surprising results.

Quoting from [Understand integer conversion rules [cert.org]](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules):

> - If the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, the operand with unsigned integer type is converted to the type of the operand with signed integer type.
> - ***Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.***

(emphasis mine)

Consider this example:

```
int s = -1;
unsigned int u = 1;
NSLog(@"%i", s < u);
// -> 0
```

The result will be `0` (false), even though `s` (`-1`) is clearly less then `u` (`1`). This happens because both values are converted to `unsigned int`, as `int` cannot represent all values that can be contained in an `unsigned int`.

It gets even more confusing if you change the type of `s` to `long`. Then, you'd get the same (incorrect) result on a 32 bit platform (iOS), but in a 64 bit Mac app it would work just fine! (explanation: `long` is a 64 bit type there, so it can represent all 32 bit `unsigned int` values.)

So, long story short: Don't compare unsigned and signed integers, especially if the signed value is potentially negative.

Answer (score 12):

You probably don't have enough compiler warnings turned on. If you turn on `-Wsign-compare` (which can be turned on with `-Wextra`) you will generate a warning that looks like the following

```
warning: signed and unsigned type in conditional expression [-Wsign-compare]
```

This allows you to place the casts in the right places if necessary and you shouldn't need to rewrite the MAX or MIN macros

Comment: Yes, that did the trick.  Of course, now my project has 107 new issues.  I wonder how many are bugs like this one.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @raider33 I would also recommend adding `-Wall` to turn on more compiler warning if you don't already have it

Comment: Since we're talking ObjC, we're likely using `clang` instead of `gcc`. So you can do better than [`-Wall`](http://assets.diylol.com/hfs/b1e/58b/811/resized/sad-all-the-things-meme-generator-turn-on-all-the-warnings-6e57ad.jpg): turn on [`-Weverything`](http://assets.diylol.com/hfs/3a0/292/5f5/resized/all-the-things-meme-generator-turn-on-all-the-warnings-5a92fa.jpg) for *all the warnings*. Then try `-Werror` for the Hard Mode achievement.

Comment: @FDinoff many thanks. I just finished cleaning up the 107 compiler warnings and two of them represented additional bugs. One was a known bug that I could never figure out why or how to reproduce.  Fixing the compiler warning nailed it.